# Tcpdump says "Illegal instruction"

Tags: linux, tcpdump

Following the tutorial on http://www.waitingforthefuture.org/2009/12/25/compiling-tcpdump-for-tomato-firmware/, I tried to compile tcpdump. I did the compilation on an Intel Pentium 4 2.26Ghz computer running Ubuntu 10.04.

My router uses a BCM3302 V2.9 CPU. However, when I run tcpdump on it, it says "Illegal instruction".

Why does this happen? What other configuration must I do before compilation?

Comment: Did you setup the crosscompile environment correctly? What out produces a  "file tcpdump" on the PC?

Comment: The output is "tcpdump: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1, statically linked, with unknown capability 0xf41 = 0x756e6700, not stripped".

Comment: Since MIPS can be big endian or little endian, check if endianess is the same for tcpdump and the other binaries on the system...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't determine the endianess of the OS. The router is using Tomato. However, I tried checking the build of the "vi" command on the router. The output is "vi: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped". Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile for the platform you plan to run things on.  This might be possible with [GCC Cross compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler#GCC_and_cross_compilation), but only if you can get the descriptions and symbol tables for the target processor.

You're getting "illegal instruction" because the software is looking for an x86 instruction on a decidedly non x86 chip

BCM3302 [appears](http://hardware4linux.info/component/7281/) to be a MIPS32 architecture chip. There are some [toolchains](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Toolchains#MIPS_SDE) available.

Comment: Thanks. However, if I do a "file tcpdump", the output is "tcpdump: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1, statically linked, with unknown capability 0xf41 = 0x756e6700, not stripped".

Comment: Huh.  Buggered if i know then.

Comment: Do you know why it brings up that error?